# jboss 7, HTTPS and strange encoding

Tags: ssl, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm trying to setup https on my Jboss 7 (7.1.1.Final).
When going over SSL I get a very strange file back intead of my plain html.

Here is how I've configured the web subsystem:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443"/>
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            <ssl name="foo-ssl" key-alias="xxxx01" password="xxxx01" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/xxxx01.keystore" verify-client="false"/>
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

now, when I go to my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">   
   </head>
    <body>
    <p>hello</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

through

```
 http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/index.html
```

I see it fine.

First question: I would have expected

```
redirect-port="8443"
```

would have forced https. How can I force it?
Apart from this here's the puzzling thing: when going to

```
 http://localhost:8443/mywebapp/index.html
```

I get a file whose contents are

```
1503 0100 0202 0a
```

What's going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For correct redirect to https you need add in your `web.xml` (of the application mywebapp):

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

See: [Specifying a Secure Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbm)

The documentation [The HTTP Connector](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/http.html) say:

> redirect-port
>
> If this **Connector** is supporting non-SSL requests, and a request is
>   received for which a matching `<security-constraint>` requires SSL
>   transport, Catalina will automatically redirect the request to the
>   port number specified here.

I hope this help.